# Why trying to add data models to database hangs visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a new table to add to my existing .NET project. I opened the edmx file and tried to add it as a data model.

Was able to choose the tables and clicked on Finish, but visual studio hangs. The process never finishes.

Comment: Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core ?

Comment: @Veverke  Entity Framework

Comment: Did you check Visual Studio's Output window for any errors (CTRL +F) ?

Comment: @Veverke the project builds fine

Comment: Maybe a good time to say goodbye to EDMX. Apart from that, it's impossible to say anything more sensible based on this scanty information.

Comment: What version of your Visual Studio is? Please update it and see if it still hangs, it is better to provide more information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DanielZhang-MSFT it's a legacy project I'm working on and it works only on Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Since your problem cannot be reproduced, I suggest you report this problem in the Developer Community:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=61&entry=problem